Relative position of a relative position in a node tree
Using a node tree with a relative positioning system, assume 'self' is at (0, 0).  The tuple represents (up steps, down steps) that are needed to get from self to any family relationship, based on the most recent common ancestor between the two positions.
For example, to get to your grandparent's node, you take 2 steps up the node tree, 0 down.  For another example, to get to your niece, you would take one step up to your parents, then 2 down to your niece.
However, the question is, how would you mathmatically determine the correct relative position using this system for the relative of a relative?  If I wanted to get the positions for the parent, child, and sibling of my grandfather, he is at (2, 0).  Those positions are [(3, 0), (1, 0) and (2, 1), and (3, 1)].  But how can I actually calculate that?
relationship_matrix = {
    (0, 0): "Self",
    (0, 1): "Child",
    (0, 2): "Grandchild",
    (0, 3): "Great-Grandchild",
    (0, 4): "Great-Great-Grandchild",
    (0, 5): "Great-Great-Great-Grandchild",
    (1, 0): "Parent",
    (2, 0): "Grandparent",
    (3, 0): "Great-Grandparent",
    (4, 0): "Great-Great-Grandparent",
    (5, 0): "Great-Great-Great-Grandparent",
    (1, 1): "Sibling",
    (1, 2): "Niece",
    (1, 3): "Great-Niece",
    (1, 4): "Great-Great-Niece",
    (1, 5): "Great-Great-Great-Niece",
    (1, 6): "Great-Great-Great-Great-Niece",
    (2, 1): "Aunt",
    (2, 2): "1st Cousin",
    (2, 3): "1st Cousin 1x removed",
    (2, 4): "1st Cousin 2x removed",
    (2, 5): "1st Cousin 3x removed",
    (2, 6): "1st Cousin 4x removed",
    (2, 7): "1st Cousin 5x removed",
    (2, 8): "1st Cousin 6x removed",
    (2, 9): "1st Cousin 7x removed",
    (2, 10): "1st Cousin 8x removed",
    (2, 11): "1st Cousin 9x removed",
    (3, 1): "Great-Aunt",
    (3, 2): "1st Cousin 1x removed",
    (3, 3): "2nd Cousin",
    ...
    }


Note that the answer isn't necessarily unique: the child of your parent can either be yourself (0, 0) or your sibling (1, 1). It should be easy enough to write an algorithm that computes all the possible relationships obtained by composing two relationships.

Using your example, the child of your grandfather can also be your aunt (2, 1). Also, the sibling of your grandfather is (3, 1), not (2, 1).

You can always go to the top of the tree first, and then back down to the target. What you are presumably looking for is a last common ancestor.

Thanks, I've corrected the expected solution list.

There is no formula as such, if that is what you are looking for. You would need an algorithm to compute it.
